# type cast and polymorphism with overloaded methods

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Is there a way to automatically cast an object to a specific type when passing that object into an overloaded method?

I have three classes that all inherit from a base class

```
class Cat : Animal
class Dog : Animal
class Tiger : Animal
```

I have another class, a class that writes to a database `(dbInterface)` that has an overloaded create method for each of these types

```
void Create(Cat cat);
void Create(Dog dog);
void Create(Tiger tiger);
```

I would like to call a Create method like so

```
Animal cat = new Cat();

dbInterface.Create(cat);
```

and I'd like this to call the `Create(Cat cat)` method specifically. Currently this doesn't happen because cat is type Animal.

Currently what I'm doing that I don't particularly like is I have a generic create method `Create(Animal animal)` and in that method I check for a valid cast and call the appropriate method.

```
void Create(Animal animal)
{
    Cat cat = animal as Cat;
    if (cat != null)
    {
         Create(cat);
    }
... for Dog and Tiger too ...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept/language feature you're looking for is called "Dynamic/Double Dispatch". For languages that don't have it, there is a technique called "The Visitor Pattern".

That should be enough to get you started, but let me find some resources I've used in the past...

Oh, wow, it turns out [C# has this feature already](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch#Double_dispatch_in_C#) when you cast the argument!

Comment: Dynamic dispatch in C# can be done surprisingly with `dynamic` :) - `dbInterface.Create((dynamic)cat);`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thanks for the help. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

unless i'm missing something, why are you overloading Create() instead of:

```
void Create(Animal animal)
```

this way any class that implements `Animal` can be passed as an  argument

```
Animal cat = new Cat();
dbInterface.Create(cat);
```

Comment: Not sure how this is different from "Currently what I'm doing that I don't particularly like is I have a generic create method `Create(Animal animal)` and in that method I check for a valid cast and call the appropriate method." stated in the post... Some clarification may help - so far it does not look like answer.

Comment: But you don't need to cast anything. The method Create takes any object that implements Animal. All the casting your' doing is unnecessary

Comment: Please show implementation for `Create(Animal)` that does what OP wants - in particular calls 3 different versions of `Create` - so it is very clear how you propose to solve double dispatch.

Comment: tbh, I don't understand what you're trying to do. `void Create(Animal animal)` in db class is all you need, and then call this method with any object as arg. it can't be simpler than that

Comment: What I was trying to do is to figure out why you believe repeating what OP said in the question is the answer. Since I think there is a good existing answer (which I used as duplicate) I don't see much reason to continue that effort on my side.